# Define time for "end_of_week"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a method that pulls out data from a database, where it's put in an array with `[date, value]` as an output (which is stored in another array, but that's details).

I am displaying the data per week, but I don't want to have the weekends with it, which is why I changed `end_of_week` to `:saturday` (pulling all data from Monday - Friday). However, this will take all the data from Monday morning 00:01 to Friday night 23:59.

Is there a way to define `end_of_week` so it stops taking data that's created after Friday 18:00?
In pseudocode it would be something like this:
`end_of_week(:friday, 18:00)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think that you are overcomplicating things

```
Time.now.end_of_week - (2.days + 6.hours)
=> 2013-10-11 17:59:59 +0200
```

would work fine.

if you really want to express a timespan from monday to friday 6 pm, i would do this

```
start = Time.now.at_beginning_of_week
=> 2013-10-07 00:00:00 +0200
ending = start + 4.days + 18.hours
=> 2013-10-12 18:00:00 +0200
```